# WatchOS storing and sharing data

Tags: ios, core-data, watchkit

I have a Core Data app. It is like a let's say a News app. Each entry has name,id,date,publisher,detail etc. Main iOS app can have lots of News entries. I only want to show let's say first 3 news with the WatchOS app. Since getting news entries needs keyboard usage, I can't initiate transfers from the Watch side. What is the good strategy to share the data? I have thought following scenarios

1. Send Core Data files with WatchConnectivity transferFile

   - PROS: Easy
   - Huge amount of unnecessary data, may not have latest data if the changes aren't saved to context yet.
2. Whenever News is added send with WatchConnectivity before saving to CoreData.

   - PROS: Always same data,
   - CONS: Huge amount of unnecessary data, extra operations to save to new database
3. When the data is saved to Core Data, query last three objects and send them.

   - PROS: Small amount of data,
   - CONS: Need to convert NSManagedObject to another object first, may send same data

Could you help me to find a better way to sync iOS app with WatchOS app? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best approach would be background transfers using the application context. That has the following advantages:

1. You don't have to care about whether your watch app is running or not. When you add your data to the application context it gets added to to a transfer queue and whenever the watch app gets active, it receives the data.
2. Every time you add your three items, the old items get overwritten. So you always have only 3 items in the queue. That's ideal for a news app, where you don't want to bother your user with old news. So sending the same data several times is no problem, only the latest data "survives".

The only downside would be that you have to serialize your `NSManagedObject`. I don't know how complex your objects are, but if they are you could use library like [HyperSync](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync) or [Groot](https://github.com/gonzalezreal/Groot)

So this is how you would then sync your phone with your app:

**1. Set up the session:**

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
    let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
    session.delegate = self
    session.activateSession()
}
```

Do this on both places: In your main app and also in the watch extension. If you are only sending data from your main app to the watch you do not need to set the delegate on the main app side.

**2. Implement the delegate method:**

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {
    // deserialize the received data, 
    // store it in CoreData on your watch 
    // and update the UI
}
```

**3. Send the data:**

```
let dataDict = latestThreeNewsObjects.serializeToDictionary() // However you achieve this ;-) 
do {
    try WCSession.defaultSession().updateApplicationContext(dataDict as! [String : AnyObject])
} catch {
    print("Cannot send data to watch: \(error)")
}
```

So then, every time you add new news items to your main app CoreData, fetch the latest three `NSManagedObjects`, serialize them into a dictionary and update your application context. This way the watch always has the latest 3 news when it gets active. When it already is active, the news get updated immediately.

One more thing: Before trying to send data to the watch, you should always check if the user has installed the app on his watch. `WCSession` has a property for that: `watchAppInstalled`. If the app is not installed, don't waste resources sending data into the abyss...

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I guess as you said I will go with route 3. Do you think Core Data is over kill on the watch part? I have like 12 properties(String,NSDate) and one array property with 1-10 items per item.

Comment: Well, you need some sort of persistence and you are already using CoreData in your main app. So using CoreData in your watch extension would be the logical decision. However maybe now would be a good time to check out RealmSwift. I've been using RealmSwift on my last two projects and I never want go back to CoreData ;-)

Comment: Yes, you have to do that to be able to transfer them to the watch extension via application context